# What does "dd" stand for?

Tags: command-history, dd, history

What does `dd` stand for? I've always referred to it colloquially as "Disk Destroyer", but what are the "official" words that make up the acronym/command?

According to [this link](http://www.roesler-ac.de/wolfram/acro/credits.htm#1) and [this link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/alt.folklore.computers/HAWoZ8g-xYk) it could be one of the following:

1. It used to stand for 'copy and convert' and was renamed 'dd' because 'cc' was already in use for the C compiler.
2. It is a remnant of 'Job Control Language' program conversion into the 'Job Entry System'.
3. It means 'data destruction'

Comment: I've always been told it meant *Dump Data*, being a unix command to dump disk files to magnetic tape (*long ago pre in pre-Linux days when sending data by tape was still common*). That's what I was told back at uni (*or at least my memory of it*), and I see no connection at all with the IBM  JCL DD .. as its descriptive in MVS JCL only, and doesn't at all relate to COPY etc; as how its used [in JCL] will be defined elsewhere in the JCL being *descriptive* only (links JCL reference to the DSN in IBM/MVS terms)

Answer (score 10):

The actual definition may have been a joke, keyboard shorthand, or obscure reference. Wikipedia has this:

> The name dd may be an allusion to the DD statement found in IBM's Job
>   Control Language (JCL),[3] where the initials stand for "Data
>   Description."[4] The command's syntax resembles the JCL statement more
>   than it does other Unix commands, so the syntax may have been a
>   joke.[3] Another explanation for the command's name is that "cc" (for
>   "convert and copy", as in the command's description) was already taken
>   by the C compiler. It is also jokingly said that dd
>   stands for "disk destroyer" or "delete data", since when used for
>   low-level operations on hard disks, a small mistake such as reversing
>   the input file and output file parameters could result in the loss of
>   some or all data on a disk.

Source: [dd (unix) on en.wikipedia.org](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_%28Unix%29)

[This page on codecoffee](http://www.codecoffee.com/tipsforlinux/articles/036.html) has some additional discussion.

Many sysadmins have come up with their own mnemonics for commands like dd(1), and, in this case, it seems pretty much anything goes!

Comment: I like disk destroyer personally